# CSS: Div resizing depending on original size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have time blocks whose size is calculated programmatically.

The objective is:

-If the content is bigger than its container, when you hover over the element it expands to show all of it.

-If the content is smaller than its container, nothing happens.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkw22eby/3/).

**Note**:

-Red means it is how it currently is.

-Green is my objective.

I'm using Angular, so a javascript solution would be accepted.

Fiddle HTML:

```css
.current {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.current:hover {
  height: auto !important;
}
.supposed {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.supposed.small:hover {
  height: auto !important;
}
.small {
  height: 50px;
}
.big {
  height: 100px;
}
.content {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="current small">
       <div class=" content">

       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="current big">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="supposed small">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="supposed big">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having in the fiddle, what should be different?

Comment: Go to the second red div, and on the lower part move the mouse around, I would like it to be, behaviourwise like the green big square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
.content {
    height: 100%;
}
.current:hover {
    height: auto !important;
}
.content:hover {
    min-height: inherit;
}
```

HTML with Angular:

```
<div class="current" ng-style="{height: calculateHeight()+'em',min-height: calculateHeight()+'em',}">
</div>
```

The setting of the content height to 100% ensures that hovering over .current equals to hovering over .content.

The setting of "height: calculateHeight()+'em'" gives the desired effect of making .current bigger if .content should bigger than .current.

The setting of "min-height: inherit" ensures that .content is allways at least as big as it was before.

@elveti: thanks for the inspiration with max-height.

Answer (score 1):

Using just CSS, instead of setting the height of the container to auto when hovering the div, you can set the overflow to visible.

This way the "hidden" inner will be seen when hovering while the container will remain the same if the inner is smaller.

```
.current:hover {
  //height: auto !important;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkw22eby/4/

Comment: The problem with this is that in my app it wouldn't look good, since there are lines in the background, to show when this event is. And also it doesn't look good :-/

Answer (score 1):

If think you could do this by using `max-height` instead of `height` on the parents and setting the height on the `.content` child.

```
.small .content {
  height: 75px;
}
.big .content {
  height: 500px;
}
.small,
.big {
  transition: max-height 0.4s; /* Animates the max-height */
}
.small {
  max-height: 100px;
}
.big {
  max-height: 150px;
}
.current:hover {
  max-height: 3000px !important; /* Will be animated to height:auto and then it stops */
}
.content {
  background-color: #369;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c4jhvd8m/